# WPF vector nice looking button

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, vector

How to create nice looking buttons using vector image?

For example: I use **inkscape** to create vector image of button. (I also know that it is possible to convert to XAML)

How to make button based on this image made in **vector editor**?

I want to set colors for some figures in this vector image on button events (MouseOver, MouseDown)

**Is there any fine tutorial for this?**

I only have found how to change whole vector image opacity on Mouse Over.

Comment: Looking for tutorial is off-topic at SO.

Comment: VS 2015 goes with Blend. It's a tool you are looking for. Search for tutorials "Blend custom button"

Comment: Does VS 2015 Community Edition contains Blend?

Comment: Dennis, many answers at stackoverflow looks like small tutorials. So it is okay, I think.

Comment: > Does VS 2015 Community Edition contains Blend? Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DrawingImage and use this as the Template for your Button.
I edit my answer so a MouseOver changes the color of one brush in the DrawingGroup - hope it helps!

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication61TemplateTestButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                        <DrawingImage>
                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V26 H26 V0 H0 Z">
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF333333" Geometry="F1 M26,26z M0,0z M0,13C0,20.18 5.82,26 13,26 20.18,26 26,20.18 26,13 26,5.82 20.18,0 13,0 5.82,0 0,5.82 0,13" />
                                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Geometry="F1 M26,26z M0,0z M24,13C24,19.07 19.065,24 13,24 6.935,24 2,19.065 2,13 2,6.935 6.935,2 13,2 19.065,2 24,6.935 24,13" />
                                </DrawingGroup>
                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        </DrawingImage>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Width="16" Height="16" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please mark as answer.

Comment: I need to make some triggers on MouseOver, MouseDown

Comment: @Alexey - I modified my answer.

Comment: @Alexey - do you have further problems?